# PIC mov command question

Tags: pic, embedded

I have a code that prints what's in the memory of my PIC18F4550 to the serial port. I'm trying to do this in two ways but only one is successfull. Can someone enlighten me why

Version one (functional, I think atleast..)
I've done some initializations and configurations prior to the code below

```
loop:
    btfsc TXSTA, 1
    movff POSTINC0, TXREG
    bra loop
```

Version two (not working..)

```
loop:
    movf POSTINC0
    btfsc TXSTA, 1
    movwf TXREG
    bra loop
```

Any ideas?

//Red

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The btfsc instruction skips the next instruction when the transmitter is not ready to accept an new byte.

In the first snippet, this next instruction copies the data byte to the transmit register (with auto address increment). The next instruction jumps back to the btfsc.

In the second snippet, the instruction that is skipped moves the content of W to the transmit resister. That is OK, but the jump jumps back to the first instruction, which loads a new W value from memory (with auto address increment) *irrespective of whether the previous value was transmitted or not*.

Comment: If I add "btfsc TXSTA, 1" to the line above the "movf POSTINC0" line, should the two examples work in the same way?

Comment: What will then happen when the first btfsc sees the transmitter not yet ready to accept a new byte, and the second one sees it ready?